# Partial derivates and integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\partial_ifdx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f\in C_c^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\partial_ifdx=0$ for all $1\le i\le n$.
I started like this. But I am definitely missing something. Can someone help me finish the proof?$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\,\partial _i f(x) \mathrm{d}x=\int \limits_{-r}^{r}\cdots \int \limits_{-r}^{r}\partial_if(x_1,...,x_i,...,x_n)\, \mathrm{d}x_1\ldots \mathrm{d}x_i\ldots \mathrm{d}x_n=\cdots = 0$$

Comment: Change the order of integration so that the $dx_i$ integral is the inner one and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Hint: If $g\in\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$ has its support in $[-r,r]$, then $$\int_{-r}^r g'(x)\,\mathrm dx=g(r)-g(-r)=0.$$

Comment: Oh god, it's always the basics. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow leoli1's comment, suppose your function is supported on $B=[-r/2,r/2]^n$.

By Fubini's theorem,
$$
\int_B f=\int_{U}\left(\int_{-r}^r\partial_if(x)dx_i\right)dx_1\cdots\hat{dx_i}\cdots dx_nn
$$
where $\hat{dx_i}$ means obmitting $dx_i$ and $U\times[0,1]^{n-1}=B$. But
$$
\int_{-r}^r\partial_if(x)dx_i=f(x_1,\cdots,x_i=r,\cdots,x_n)-f(x_1,\cdots,x_i=-r,\cdots,x_n)=0-0=0
$$